# Euclidean distance from just one feature in a raster layer or polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, spatial-analyst, distance

I have a raster layer ( that I converted in polygon as well) in which there are villages (black in the picture). I would like to do a euclidean distance but just from this feature "village". I was thinking to extract just this feature but I don't know how to do.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Raster Approach: The black areas have a unique value (or range of values).  Use the Reclassify tool in ArcGIS. Give the village value(s) a new reclassified value of 1 and all other values a new reclassified value of NoData.

Vector approach 1:  Start an edit session on your polygons.  Select all polygons that are not villages.  Delete the selected polygons.  Save your edits.

Vector approach 2:  Select all the village polygons.  Run the euclidean distance tool on the polygons.  All tools in ArcGIS only operate on selected features when some data are selected.